# How to determine the type depending on the return value from a function

Tags: typescript

My type:

```
type Shortcode = `[__${number}__]`;
type ShortcodeKey = number;
```

My validate `function`:

```
function isWordShortCode(code: string): boolean {
  // Some logic..
}
```

In code:

```
function getShortcodeKey(shortcode: Shortcode): ShortcodeKey {
  // Some logic..
}

// element - string
// for example: 'test' or '[__321__]'(valid shortcode)

if (isWordShortCode(element)) {
  const shortcode_key = this.getShortcodeKey(element); // Error

  // ...
}
```

> **Error**: TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '`[__${number}__]`'

I can fix it like this: `this.getShortcodeKey(element as Shortcode);`

But I don't think this is a good solution. How to write the validation function correctly so that TypeScript also understands what type will be next?

TypeScript version: **4.3.4**.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgewE7AMYICbQLxQAYDaA%20kQCQDeAdgK4C2ARhEgL4kC6eA3AFCiSyIU6LAGkIIKLhoMmPbgDNqlVMACWCSlA0AbEAHVkGeMmABhTBADOACkvAkALih2kqygHMAlE5dv3BNigAHygabW0ocm4oKHRKOygkCHcIAA9JKAB6AB1iImyMAGp2TPdaORik4GokTRcAOloAQzQ4aySU1M8eZm4FJRV1TVVLAyQjQTMLa2EIH3s-byh6BARtCCbNKJiYuISXDJ19Q2MUcywbWc9onYB%20eoIABjYbmPvm1uscvILiojZMtcdlB7k8XsD7kkwNomqgIF9HoVMgAaKAAcjR3T6lQg1VqznsrxBWVyJF%20JXqwCswFs9iBOyc8ia2ksEB6fX6yjUGigKWApzQFjEIFsk1mTgFVwlYqF4ki0SqNTqMqwRJi9Us0NUNLRJExaqg9Xkqm0VKQ1hwAD4oABCG2FCD04GNJpgC2Sa0Ozxg9l9PbAKAQda0CCUAO4NEAFWpzgQIageQAjOwoNGEvUM1BUQB2AAcAE4EyQAMzsNFyf2xOBKADWlgyQYgIbDGq1NMy1lJ%20SK7E8gIr1codZdbsbzfD1u2O1U8ig1hGYwmJnO8LHoeAnk88uBlcsKogRBrctwfMlspFa7DWKJzKYOoA8jXMTxgb1mN0gA)

Comment: pls share reproducable example. Where did you get `element` from? What type of the `element`? what is `ShortcodeKey`?

Comment: If the function `getShortcodeKey` can accept strings other than those of type `Shortcode` then you should type it as such

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković please, give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to return a type guard instead of a boolean:

```
export type Shortcode = `[__${number}__]`;
export type ShortcodeKey = number;

function isWordShortCode(code: string): code is Shortcode { // Type Guard
    return true;
}

function getShortCodeKey(shortcode: Shortcode): ShortcodeKey {
    return;
}
declare const element: string;
if (isWordShortCode(element)) {
    const shortcode_key = getShortCodeKey(element);
}
```

Comment: Is it relevant now to use guard? Since the page(https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) is out of date.

Comment: Of course. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates